# Inserting an element

Tags: javascript

Is there a method in Javascript to insert an element after the current node.I know there is a method  which inserts an element before the current node of the XML.But is there a method to Ins. after the current node?

Answer (score 11):

Just get the next sibling of the current node and insert the new node before that node using [`insertBefore`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-952280727):

```
currentNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, currentNode.nextSibling);
```

If `nextSibling` is `null`, `insertBefore` inserts the new node at the end of the node list.

Comment: I hate this syntax, but this is the only way. +1

Comment: Something neat is that only `currentNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, currentNode.nextSibling)` is needed. If currentNode.nextSibling is `null`, the outcome is exactly that of the appendChild line anyway.

Comment: @Gumbo, perhaps it's worth updating this as per crescentfresh's comment?

Answer (score -1):

There is no direct method to insert a node after a specific node but there is a workaround:

```
var parent = currentNode.parentNode;
if(currentNode.nextSibling != null)
    parent.insertBefore(newNode,currentNode.nextSibling)
else
    parent.appendChild(newNode);
```

Comment: No, that's incorrect. `insertBefore` with `null` as the reference element inserts at the *end* of the parent node (e.g., it's the same as `appendChild`). No need at all for the check.