# Append to div, rather than body

Tags: javascript, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inserting an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559621/inserting-an-element)
>   [How to do insert After() in JavaScript without using a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-do-insert-after-in-javascript-without-using-a-library)

I have this little bit of javascript in a project which adds a chat window after the body of the page, I'd like to change it so that it adds the chat window AFTER my specified div "myPublisherDiv". I think this is pretty simple, any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('id', 'stream' + streams[i].streamId);
    document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: Mmh, I just noticed that your title and the text of your question differ... if you only want to append, it seems you just need to learn about `getElementById`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById

Comment: FYI, `div.setAttribute('id', 'stream' + streams[i].streamId);` can be written `div.id = 'stream' + streams[i].streamId;`; [`id` is a *reflected property* on elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-63534901) and is universally supported.

Answer (score 1):

Put an id to your div

```
<div id="myDiv">..</div>
```

And then append things to it with the [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.appendChild):

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(div);
```

Comment: That actually replaces just the content.

Comment: @Amberlamps oops, I mean `+=`

Comment: Using `+=` with `innerHTML` is an anti-pattern which causes the browser to do a **lot** more work than required, and wipes out event handlers on the content within. Use `appendChild`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the suggestion, I didn't know it was that bad

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit trickier. [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.insertBefore) is simple, for inserting after a node I wrote a litte helper function:

```
function insertAfter(newElement, referenceElement) {
    referenceElement.parentNode.insertBefore(newElement, referenceElement.nextSibling);
}

var div = document.createElement('div');
...
insertAfter(document.getElementById("myPublisherDiv"), div);
```

But see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/1559632/1048572

Comment: Rather use `nextSibling` instead of `nextNode`

Comment: Oops, already edited. Thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it..

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute('id', 'stream' + streams[i].streamId);

var target = document.getElementById('myPublisherDiv');

target.parentNode.insertBefore(div, target.nextSibling);
```

ripped from [How to do insert After() in JavaScript without using a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-do-insert-after-in-javascript-without-using-a-library)

Comment: Shouldn't you vote to close it as a duplicate then? ;)

Comment: just did.. *<excuse> i did update the code to match the OP's code, doesn't that count for something ? :p </excuse>*